# Machine learning and python NLP

Tags: machine-learning

I want to work with fake news detection with my country newspaper language,   I Want to compare   fake and real news with machine learning  how can   machine give me answer which news is fake or real?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot apply just machine learning. Just think about it: you cannot detect a fake news just analyzing it. You have to have a prior knowledge and compare it to the idea of the world that you have. 
The only approach you could use is to cluster the news into clusters that tell about the same news, then, if try to compare different news that talk about the same topic and find some inconsistency. Is it a "AI-complete" problem though.